# contents().find() not producing the same result as changing selector context? - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that looks somewhat like this:

```
function(domObj) {
    var currentObj = $(domObj);
    ...
    currentObj.contents().find(".ws").after("foobar");
}
```

My problem is that the above method of using `.contents().find()` is not working. "foobar" never gets stuffed after the specified dom element, represented by the selector, `.ws`

However if I do this:

```
$(".ws", currentObj).after("foobar");
```

Then the string, "foobar" gets appended every time.

My question:

Are not these two methods supposed to be equivilant? How/what am I doing wrong in my use of `.contents().find()` so that it is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".ws", currentObj).after("foobar");
```

... is equivelant to:

```
currentObj.find(".ws").after("foobar");
```

[`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) returns all child-nodes, and so therefore when you execute `contents().find()` you're actually searching *within* the child-nodes, as opposed to searching the child-nodes themselves.

Comment: hold up, then why did `.children().after()` work for me? *confused*

Comment: `children()` returns the children too, but you're not executing `children().find()`, you're just executing `children()`, so if you call `children('.ws')` you're basically saying: "gimme the children with a class of `ws`", as opposed to `contents().find('.ws')` which is saying "gimme the children, then look within those children for an element with a class of `ws`."